# using if to find avg in laravel

Tags: laravel, average

i want to showing count avg using if, but not working,

this my code,

```
public function update(Request $request,Pt $pt)
{
    $query = DB::table('macs');
    if ($request->loin == 'AA/A') {
    $query->whereIn('sap_code',['108591','108592'])->avg('mac');
    }

    if ($request->loin == 'B') {
        $query->where('sap_code','108593')->avg('mac');
    }

    $mac = $query->get('mac');

    Pt::where('id',$pt->id)->update([
        'lbs' => $request->lbs,
        'loin' => $request->loin,
        'mac' => $mac
    ]);
}
```

thank you

Comment: if loin not equals to 'AA/A' and 'B', what value do u want?

Comment: i already make default input for loin equals 'AA/A' or 'B'.

Comment: so the `$request->loin` only equals to `AA/A` or `B`?

Comment: yes, only AA/A or B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you using [avg-method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates), it will return the value directly.

```php
if ($request->loin == 'AA/A') {
   $mac = DB::table('macs')->whereIn('sap_code',['108591','108592'])->avg('mac');
} else {
   $mac = DB::table('macs')->where('sap_code','108593')->avg('mac');
}
```

And you can use [when](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses) instead of `if`:

```php
$mac = DB::table('macs')
    ->when(($request->loin == 'AA/A'), function ($query) {
        return $query->whereIn('sap_code',['108591','108592']);
    })
    ->when(($request->loin == 'B'), function ($query) {
        return $query->where('sap_code', '108593');
    })
    ->avg('mac');
```